# Botman.io Facebook Template error

Tags: chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I have copied and pasted the example from the document, with the bunch of includes at the top:

```
use Mpociot\BotMan\Facebook\GenericTemplate;
use Mpociot\BotMan\Facebook\ListTemplate;
use Mpociot\BotMan\Facebook\ButtonTemplate;
use Mpociot\BotMan\Facebook\ElementButton;
use Mpociot\BotMan\Facebook\Element;

$botman->reply(ButtonTemplate::create('Do you want to know more about BotMan?')
                ->addButton(ElementButton::create('Tell me more')->type('postback')->payload('tellmemore'))
                ->addButton(ElementButton::create('Show me the docs')->url('http://botman.io/'))
            );
```

but it gave me error:

```
  [ErrorException]
  Object of class Mpociot\BotMan\Facebook\ButtonTemplate could not be convert
  ed to string
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause; The Console Driver is not handling the Facebook Template; Hopefully will fix in the future release. This works on Facebook Messager though.